# Unable loading an image on server

Tags: php, image, upload, loading

uploadImg.php:

```
<?php

//CHECK EXISTENCIA ARCHIVO

if((!empty($_FILES["ex1"])) && ($_FILES['ex1']['error'] == 0)) {

  //CHECK NOMBRE

  $filename = basename($_FILES['ex1']['name']);

  // CHECK EXTENSIÓN

  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

  //CHECK FORMATO

  if (
    (
        ($ext == "jpg") || ($ext == "jpeg") || ($ext == "png") || ($ext == "gif") 
    ) && (
        ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
    ) && (
        ($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 300000)
    )
    ) {


      //NOMBRE ÚNICO TIMESTAMP

      $time=time();  
      $newname = '/../uploads/'.$time.'.'.$ext;


      //CHECK DUPLICIDAD

      if (!file_exists($newname)) {


          //SUBIDA

          if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ex1']['tmp_name'],$newname.'.'.$ext))) {
           echo 'Imgen subida: '.$newname;
        } else {
           echo 'No subida:'.$newname;
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: El archivo ".$_FILES["ex1"]["name"]." ya existe";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Tamaño máximo excedido (300kb) o formato erróneo (jpg, png, gif)";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No existe el archivo";
}
?>
```

When trying to upload image, I always receive: `

> Error: A problem occurred during the rise in
>   /var/www/html/panel/actions/../uploads/1430908419.jpg

`

Directory is correct as far as I am concerned:

uploadImg.php is on: `/var/www/html/panel/actions/uploadImg.php`
final directory is on: `/var/www/html/panel/uploads`

Comment: `echo  dirname(__FILE__).'/../uploads/'.$time.'.'.$ext;` and see whats output

Comment: Hi. Have you read the question? What is being echoed is right that ($newname has right that stored). It echoes: /var/www/html/panel/actions/../uploads/1430909778.jpg

Comment: what you getting from this? `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Thanks for your attention. This is what dirname(__FILE__) shows: /var/www/html/panel/actions

Comment: post the solution check\

Answer (score -1):

this is your Error.

**Error: A problem occurred during the rise in /var/www/html/panel/actions/../uploads/1430908419.jpg**

If you check the error it tells your pathis incorrect **panel/actions/../uploads/**.

if your `actions` folder and `uploads` folder in same root, in above path  **/actions/** this should be removed.

so problem is with your folder path.

try this

```
$newname = '/../uploads/'.$time.'.'.$ext;
```

Comment: huh... sorry but not solved... it stills the same. I thought it was solved but nope

Comment: I have updated code on question, widthout the dirname as it is now. Error now is: "No subida:/../uploads/1430910765.jpg"

Comment: can you tell folder structurer of server

Comment: Isn't it what is at the end of the question? In case not explain me what you need please. I also think this must be some structure issue, but dont find any mistake

Comment: what is your project main directory name??

Comment: It is "panel". Tht directory contains the actions directory (insde we have the uploadImg.php) and the uploads directory

Comment: ok. from where you uploading this file(your upload php file inside which dir??)

Comment: uploadImg.php is on: /var/www/html/panel/actions/uploadImg.php -----
final directory is on: /var/www/html/panel/uploads

Comment: Solved: directory had no permissions